# Aurelia auth login issue

Tags: javascript, aurelia, aurelia-auth

I have the following problem with aurelia-auth, here is common login snippet that I use:

```js
login() {
    return this.authService.login(this.email, this.password)
    .then(response => {
        console.log("Login response" + JSON.stringify(response));
    })
    .catch(err => {
        this.loginError = err.response;
    });
};
```

When I'm trying to login, I see desired console output, but also there is a message **"login route : /login" from authorizeStep.js:38**
which states that I'm actually not authenticated

My auth-config:

```js
var config = {
  baseUrl: '',
  loginUrl:'http://localhost:8888/rest-auth/login/',
  signupUrl: 'http://localhost:8888/rest-auth/registration/',
  loginRedirect: '#/contests',
  logoutRedirect: '/',
  tokenName: 'key',
  authHeader: 'Authorization',
  authToken: 'Token',
  storage: 'sessionstorage'
}
export default config;
```

app.js:

```js
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';
import AppRouterConfig from 'router-config';
import HttpClientConfig from 'aurelia-auth/app.httpClient.config';
import {FetchConfig} from 'aurelia-auth';

@inject(Router, HttpClientConfig, FetchConfig, AppRouterConfig)
export class App {

  constructor(router, httpClientConfig, fetchConfig, appRouterConfig {
    this.router = router;
    this.httpClientConfig = httpClientConfig;
    this.appRouterConfig = appRouterConfig;
    this.fetchConfig = fetchConfig;
  }

  activate() {
    this.httpClientConfig.configure();
    this.appRouterConfig.configure();
    this.fetchConfig.configure();
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.